# Salvar dados de atributo data em um input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário e gostaria de pegar os valores do atributos 'data-aliquota' e colocar dentro de um input invisível. Não sei como posso fazê-lo.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="cidade" data-aliquota="1.00" name="cidade" value="salvador" />
  <input type="text" id="estado" data-aliquota="2.00" name="estado" value="bahia" />
  <input type="hidden" name="valores" id="valores" />
</form>
```

A saída deveria ser algo do tipo: "**1.00,2.00**"

Comment: use attr do jQuery http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para pegar os valores de aliquota. No exemplo eu armazenei todas as aliquotas em um array e inseri esse array ao `input hidden`

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var aliquotas = [];
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).data("aliquota") >= 0){
            aliquotas.push($(this).data("aliquota"));
        }
    });
    
    $("#valores").val(aliquotas);
    
    console.log($("#valores").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="cidade" data-aliquota="1.00" name="cidade" value="salvador" />
  <input type="text" id="estado" data-aliquota="2.00" name="estado" value="bahia" />
  <input type="hidden" name="valores" id="valores" />
</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, @JrD. Obrigado.